# Progress bar adding a threshold line

Tags: qt

I've progress bar to display the instantaneous value of real-time sensor.

the range for the `QProgressBar` is set as

```
ui->progressBar->setRange(0, 0.5*100); // to make range integer

ui->progressBar->setValue(sensor_read*100);
```

It is working ok. But I need to set a "threshold" value using a `doubleSpinBox` , as shown below:

[image]

The position of the dotted line (which is a `QLabel`) is the threshold that can be set using a `doubleSpinBox`.

My requirement is to change the height of the dotted line with respect to the threshold value.

the top and bottom `y` coordinates of the `QProgressBar` is `250` and `450`

How do I get proportional `y` coordinate for the `QLabel` (dotted line) when I set a threshold value using `doubleSpinBox`?

Answer (score 0):

Using a QLabel is possible, but it might be hard to get the exact position of the line inside the QLabel itself to adjust correctly. If your QLabel is only 1px high, this should work fine, otherwise you would need to adjust a bit more in detail.

So if the QLabel has the QProgressBar set as parent, then you can set the y coordinate of the QLabel inside the QProgressBar accordingly with something like below.

Call this function every time the threshold is modified, or when the widget (i.e. the progress bar) is resized. This is done by connecting on the signal:

```
connect(spinBox, &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged, this, &MyClass::updateThreshold);

void MyClass::updateThreshold()
{
    const double threshold = spinBox->value();
    int labelY = qRound(threshold / progressBar->maximum() * progressBar->height());
    label->move(0, progressBar->height() - labelY); // y is inverted
}

void MyClass::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    updateThreshold();
}
```

Another way is to create a new class that inherits QProgressBar and to override the `paintEvent()` function. Inside the paintEvent, you could draw a horizontal line and the text using the QPainter at the correct position, using the same calculation than above. There you would not need a QLabel.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer. But I'm not getting the expected output. Basically `singleStep` for `spinBox` is `0.02`. With the above calculation I'm getting one step movement after every  6 `spinBox` presses. What may be the problem?